# JQuery load with fadein/out causes flashing

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have an images page.

```
<div id="contentWrap">
    <?php include 'images.php'; ?>
</div>
```

I am testing with a single image and script in the images.php, but I plan to use a dozen or so. I am trying to.

- Fade out group of images on 'images.php'
- Load php file for the selected image 'image1.php'
- Fade in content on 'image1.php

At the moment, everything is working fine but I get a double flash both on fadeOut of 'images.php' and fadeIn of 'image1.php' and vice versa. As if the image was fading out twice, then fading in twice. This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Images.php

```
<div id="contentWrap">

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#image1').click(function() {
    $('#contentWrap').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#contentWrap').load("http://example.com/image1.php");
    $('#contentWrap').fadeIn('slow');
});
});
<script>

<a id="image1" class="pics" href="#">
    <img src="aPicture.jpg">
</a>

<a id="image2" class="pics" href="#">
    <img src="anotherPicture.jpg">
</a>

....
```

Image1.php

```
<div id="contentWrap">

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.back').click(function() {
    $('#contentWrap').fadeOut('slow');
     $('#contentWrap').load("http://example.com/images.php");
         $('#contentWrap').fadeIn('slow');
});
});
</script>

<a class="back" href="#">back</a>
<img src="image1-large.jpg">
<img src="image1-effects.jpg">
</div>
```

Is there a better way to do this and how to avoid the double fade effect?

I thought this was being caused by using the ID contentWrap twice, but I am still getting undesired effects when I change the ID on one of the pages and script.

Answer (score 0):

Remove script tags from the #contentWrap div and move them somewhere outside it (maybe in head section or seperate js file?). Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybwg3tor/)

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#image1').click(function() {

    $('#contentWrap').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#contentWrap').load("http://example.com/image1.php");
    $('#contentWrap').fadeIn('slow');

});

$('.back').click(function() {

    $('#contentWrap').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#contentWrap').load("http://example.com/images.php");
    $('#contentWrap').fadeIn('slow');

});

});

</script>

<div id="contentWrap">

<a id="image1" class="pics" href="#">
    <img src="aPicture.jpg">
</a>

<a id="image2" class="pics" href="#">
    <img src="anotherPicture.jpg">
</a>

<div id="contentWrap">

<a class="back" href="#">back</a>
    <img src="image1-large.jpg">
    <img src="image1-effects.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't quite working for me. Function for #image one fires, but the one for .back does not.

Comment: For me both functions seem to fire